# If an object had an acceleration only in the time dimension relative to an observer, what would it look like to an observer?

Tags: kinematics, spacetime, thought-experiment

The other day I was thinking about how an object moving away from an observer in spatial dimensions appears to get smaller as it gets further away.

That made me wonder- if there was an object that was stationary in the spatial dimensions relative to some observer, but moving away in the time dimension only, what would that look like?  Is it even possible, or am I misunderstanding the nature of spacetime?  Would the object get smaller even as it appeared to stay in the same physical location?

Comment: What does "moving away in the time dimension  only" mean?

Comment: Do you mean an object with only the time component of the 4-velocity equal to zero? If so it is just an object at rest in that reference frame, nothing special.

Comment: Time dilation in non uniform gravity can cause objects and observers to observe different passage of time between each other at different elevations even if they are stationary relative to each other.

Comment: The four-velocity of an object is always $c$. This immediately implies that four-acceleration must be perpendicular to four-velocity. So the time component of four-velocity cannot change without changing the spatial components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both velocity and acceleration are not purely spatial concepts; they are concepts related to both space and time. In spacetime terms they relate to the relative gradient of one worldline or another. So what a non-physicist might refer to as a "spatial" acceleration is really a statement about what is going on in time as well as space.

With this in mind, one cannot easily give sense to the idea of a "purely temporal" acceleration, but perhaps one way to do it is to say it refers to getting further away in time in the sense of aging more quickly according to internal dynamics. For example, an object located higher up in a gravitational field will age more quickly. The observation here would be that as you sit at your location experiencing life at what feels to you like a normal pace, your friend at a higher location is getting through more heart-beats, and having faster cell division, and faster chemistry and particle physics and everything, as indicated by all your observations of them from your location. The effect would only be noticeable in extreme conditions of course.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  These are some great answers!

Comment: Also I don't know why this question is closed as being off-topic for mainstream physics... I was posing a legitimate thought experiment based on my limited understanding of spacetime in an attempt to further my understanding

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of confusion in this question. In the title it says “acceleration only in the time dimension” and in the body of the question it says “moving away in the time dimension only”. The latter statement makes no sense because “away” is a spatial direction and it doesn’t apply to time in any fashion that I can conceive. However, the question in the title does have an answer.

In relativity, the four-dimensional vector describing acceleration is unimaginatively called the four-acceleration. Which is equal to the four-force divided by the mass. So an object which is at rest with respect to an observer and accelerating in the time direction would be undergoing a four-force with only a time component.

The time component of the four-force is essentially power. So such an object would either be releasing power (losing mass) or absorbing power (gaining mass)